# Help with a tricky passage of ecclesiastical Latin

Tags: latin-to-english-translation, ecclesiastical-latin

I'm having a bit of trouble with the following sentence, that comes in a description of David's temple.

> Ex hac igitur animi magnitudine et pietate regis potentissimi et
> pientissimi intelligendum reliquit quale esset tabernaculum quod
> preparaverat Domino talis ac tantus rex tali tantaeque Maiestati.

It's *reliquit* that's throwing me off. Should we take as equivalent to *reliquitur*, i.e. "it remains that/we're left to understand of what sort was the tabernacle"?

Also, should the prepositional phrase that begins the sentence be taken as description of why *reliquit*? Or a description of the evidence from which *intelligendum*?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you give the preceding sentence? Is there a possible subject for *reliquit* in the previous context?

Comment: Sorry—the subject of the previous sentence is unclear: it could be David or it could be the Bible, or it could be quasi-impersonal: Pro domo Dei aedificanda omnes thesauros suos exposuit, nam aiebat: 'Domus....quam aedificari volo Domino, talis esse debet, ut in cunctis regionibus nominetur.' Ex hac igitur...

Comment: I think the subject is clearly David: "he left it to be understood..."

Comment: This does make the most sense to me, too—though I just didn't quite get the grammar.

Comment: Why can't the subject of "reliquit" be the clause "quale esset tabernaculum quod preparaverat Domino talis ac tantus rex tali tantaeque Maiestati"?

Comment: I don't quite see the sense there—could you elaborate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the additional context you provided points to David being the subject:

> Pro domo Dei aedificanda omnes thesauros suos exposuit, nam aiebat: 'Domus....quam aedificari volo Domino, talis esse debet, ut in cunctis regionibus nominetur.' Ex hac igitur animi magnitudine et pietate regis potentissimi et pientissimi intelligendum reliquit quale esset tabernaculum quod preparaverat Domino talis ac tantus rex tali tantaeque Maiestati.

That is: "He spent all his treasures on building the house of God, for he said: 'The house ... which I wish to build for the Lord ought to be such that it will be spoken of in all regions.' So out of this greatness of soul and piety of a most powerful and pious king he left it to be understood of what kind was the tabernacle that he had prepared for the Lord, such and so great a king to such and so great a Majesty."

This translation is over-literal, but I think it reflects the intended syntax. At least, it's hard to see what else the subject of *reliquit* could be if not David.

Comment: I think this is a reasonable reconstruction of the author's intention, but the personal active use of this verb is very odd. There is a passage in Lucretius with a quasi-impersonal second-person subjunctive: quod cohibet solidum constare relinquas. There's also a generic pronominal subject in Celsus: illud non relinquit, ut... (that does not leave [ut-clause] as the conclusion). We have the same impersonal construction in English: "I can rule out A, B, and C, so that leaves D as the correct answer."

Comment: @Kingshorsey Why do you say it's odd? It looks to me like a normal use of the verb.

Comment: This verb does not combine a personal active form with an object-clause. It usually uses an impersonal passive with a subject clause. And I gave the two passages I found where there's an impersonal active. See OLD, 14.

Comment: @Kingshorsey I read it as having an implied *id*, with which the *quale* clause is in apposition: "he left (this) to be understood, (namely)..."

Comment: Yes, that is exactly the kind of construction one does not find, so far as I can tell, with the personal active.

Comment: Let me put it another way. In Cicero, we read: "relinquitur ergo, ut omnia tria genera sint causarum." I don't believe there is any valid way of transforming this impersonal passive into a personal, active sentence with the same meaning: "Cicero ergo relinquit omnia tria genera esse causarum."

Comment: @Kingshorsey Maybe there happen to be no exact parallels attested, but any transitive verb can take an *id* as object, so I'm not sure we need them. And the meaning here is different from your Cicero and Celsius examples (which are about options "remaining" rather than someone "leaving behind" something). LSJ has examples with an infinitival object clause: *Poet., with obj.-clause: “(metus) Omnia suffundens mortis nigrore, neque ullam Esse voluptatem liquidam puramque relinquit,” Lucr. 3, 40; 1, 703; Ov. M. 14, 100: “dum ex parvo nobis tantundem haurire relinquas,” Hor. S. 1, 1, 52*.

Comment: @Kingshorsey Here's a parallel example: https://latin.packhum.org/loc/2349/5/1070/188-192,193-201#1070

Comment: In English, we can use "leave" with an AcI rather freely. "You left me to die!" "Oh no, I left the cookies to burn in the oven!" But classical Latin seems to avoid doing so. However, your examples from Horace (slightly different construction, but same principle) and Servius demonstrate that such a development did occur. Thanks for the discussion.

Comment: The Servius to me (albeit my much lesser Latinitas) does seem like a clincher. But I should also note that the author, Lawrence of Brindisi, is by no means an orthodox Latinist, and sometimes does seem to be translating from Italian in his head.